# SQL при запросе исключить определенное значение столбца

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Есть столбец `id`, который к примеру хранит 3 значения (1,2,3). Как сделать запрос на получение всех значений кроме 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table where id != 3
```

Для нескольких значений можно так:

```
select * from table where id NOT IN (2, 3)
```